# Использование getattr в python

Tags: python, pyqt, импорт, плагин, getattr

Есть программа. Она открывает файлы различных типов. Для этих файлов разные функции открытия. Но открытие определённого типа файла должно быть плагином. Есть словарь типов данных и функция их открывающих.

```
types = {"file": "fileOpen"}
```

Плагин будет импортироваться как

```
plugin = __import__("plugin", None, None, [''])
```

В плагине будет импорт словаря и добавление возможности открытия нового типа файлов

```
types["image"] = "imageOpen"
def imageOpen():
     ...
```

В программе при открытии файла через `getattr` будет находить правильную функцию открытия и выполнять её.

Итак вопрос: getattr должна искать функцию открытия во всех импортированных плагинах и их классах + класс главной программы. Можно ли сделать так? Если нет, то объясните пожалуйста как можно реализовать этою Заранее спасибо!